# Spring Integration DSL: wont execute other components after executing routeToRecipients

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-integration, messaging, dsl

Upon running the application, the flow stops at routeToRecipients and other components were not executed. (See the inline comments in the code below)
No error occured.

But when I remove the routeToRecipients(), other components execute.

Is there something wrong with my integration flow?

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface gateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "request.input")
    void process(List<Msg> test);
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedDelay(1000).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("request.input")
            .split()
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .transform(this.transformer::transform)
            .routeToRecipients(r -> 
                    r.recipient("channel1")
                     .recipient("channel2")
                     .recipient("channel3")
                     .recipient("channel4"))
            .transform(this.transformer::transform2) // <---this is not executed :(
            .handle(new GenericHandler<Msg>() {     // <---this too is not executed
                @Override
                public Object handle(Msg payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    System.out.println("test service activator!");
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("channel1")
            .handle(new GenericHandler<Msg>() {
                @Override
                public Object handle(Msg payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    System.out.println("Test route Channel 1")
                    return payload;
                }
            })
            .channel("output")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("channel2")
            .handle(new GenericHandler<Msg>() {
                @Override
                public Object handle(Msg payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    System.out.println("Test route Channel 2")
                    return payload;
                }
            })
            .channel("output")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow3() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("channel3")
            .handle(new GenericHandler<Msg>() {
                @Override
                public Object handle(Msg payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    System.out.println("Test route Channel 3")
                    return payload;
                }
            })
            .channel("output")
            .get();
}

    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow4() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("channel4")
            .handle(new GenericHandler<Msg>() {
                @Override
                public Object handle(Msg payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    System.out.println("Test route Channel 4")
                    return payload;
                }
            })
            .channel("output")
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A router does not have an output channel - it only sends messages to the recipients.

You can either put a publish/subscribe channel before the router with the router being one subscriber and the remaining flow the second subscriber.

Or add channel5 and start the remaining flow (in a new flow) with that channel.

Comment: Thanks Gary! This really helps. :)

Comment: How to add channel5? in place of .transform(this.transformer::transform2)? I thought  in xml based config, it is possible to aggregate and continue to next components. is that not  right. I have the same problem now, as we are using DSL. any help on flow to continue to other components appreciated

Comment: @KrisSwat Don't ask a new question (especially when unclear) in comments on 4 year-old answers; ask a new question showing your flow DSL.

Comment: @KrisSwat It's too hard to answer such questions in the abstract; you need to show your specific code and what you have tried. In the case above, `channel5` would be another recipient and the remaining flow (after the router) is put in another flow, starting with `channel5`. I thought that was clear from my answer; hence I thought you were looking for something else.

Comment: Important Questions like these dont get a single upvote, and so stackoverflow will ban users from asking questions, as these are counted as less popular.  Question - router does not have output channel. Agreed. How to have more handle methods or other, after route to recipients and continue the same flow? The FMail java from spring-integration examples [dsl si4demo] also stop at .routeToRecipients. what I want is - say a handler after  routetorecipients , so that it is applied to  both -  not duplicating in 2 different flows

Comment: You cannot; the recipient list router ends the flow.

Comment: If you want to aggregate the results from each recipient, you should use a `.scatterGather()` EIP method instead - hence my suggestion to open a new question. 
 [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605348/is-there-a-way-to-fork-the-spring-integrationflow-using-dsl/63605570#63605570).

Comment: I dont want to aggregate results. I tried  the flow f->f.publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c.subscribe(firstflow()).suscribe(secondflow())).handle(someactivator); flow wise ok, but I do not know the impact.  Till now all are direct - like .handle(service1).handle(service2)...I dont want control to jump to the last - will the handle(someactivator) called only after subscribers flows are complete? or async?

Comment: Pubsub is sync by default. You said aggregate in your first comment. One more time. Ask a new question next time.

Comment: Stackoverflow doesnt allow me to ask new question. It wants popular questions...more votes. Spring Integration forum was closed in favour of stackoverflow [ i think i remember why the forum was closed]. Sorry for using aggregate in first comment. I only meant it was possible in xml. would be great, if you can help here. Question: current flow :  starts at a channel, handle handle handle....finish. Now - want more than 1 consumer at every handle.No need to aggregate. if 1 subscriber is not required, we will remove that recipient etc